# nested validation - model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have two linked models (simplified) :

Ad :

```
class Ad < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :propositions
validates :pricemin
validates :pricemax
...
```

Proposition :

```
class Proposition < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :ad
attr_accessible :price_proposition
...
```

I'm trying to add a restriction for the price_proposition (in "proposition" model) to be between "pricemin" and "pricemax".

How could I do that ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Your need to create a jquery validate

Comment: Here is an example http://bestror.wordpress.com/2013/06/29/validation-form-in-ruby-on-rails-with-jquery-validate/

Answer (score 1):

Client side validation via Javascript is definitely one way to go. But if you want to do server side validation, you can do something like this:

```
class Proposition < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :ad
  attr_accessible :price_proposition

  validate :price_proposition_in_range

  def price_proposition_in_range
    pricemin = self.ad.pricemin
    pricemax = self.ad.pricemax
    if self.price_proposition < pricemin || self.price_proposition > pricemax
      errors.add(:price_proposition, "Must be between #{pricemin} and #{pricemax}")
    end
  end

  .
  .
  .
end
```

And of course, you can add further checks in the method, depending on whether you want to allow blank or not etc etc.